# Bot Framework Composer doesn't recognize custom function

Tags: bot-framework-composer

I need to execute some logic in a Composer bot that is not possible to do in Adaptive Expressions, so I went ahead and followed this instructions to create a custom function that I'm suppossed to be able to call from an Adaptive Expression in composer.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/language-generation/bot-builder-howto-use-lg-custom-functions?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs#add-a-custom-function-to-adaptive-expressions

Then I added the function name into the settings like it's indicated here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-validate#custom-functions

Running from composer or from the cli I get the same error:
Application startup exception
System.Data.SyntaxErrorException: {NAME_OF_FUNCTION_HERE} does not have an evaluator, it's not a built-in function or a custom function.

Comment: But the composer does not have a BOTS folder to add the custom functions. Where we need to add the custom functions in composer. Can you help with this? I read the documentation links which you placed above. But no use

Comment: @mukundhareddy Are you using composer version 2?

Answer (score 0):

Classic, found the solution on the first 5 minutes of Monday.

Solution: you must do

```
Expression.Functions.Add(...
```

before loading the rootDialog.

Since loading the rootDialog was extracted into a different method I didn't realize I was actually adding the custom function after that.

Comment: Are you saying the code you've added to your custom runtime has gotten rid of the warning in Composer? Or are you just saying the custom function works when you actually run the bot?

Comment: It was never a warning in composer, it was an error at runtime. This fixed the error at runtime.

Comment: I wonder why Composer isn't giving you a warning when you use a function it doesn't recognize

Comment: During development and for intellisense, I believe composer just checks the CustomFunctions array in the settings. But then the function is loaded at runtime, there's no way composer would know before that

Comment: Where do you put Expression.Functions.Add(...???

Comment: A long time has passed, but I was doing it in  the constructor of the bot class. Now this is not needed since you can add it as a component in Composer 2 and it will take care of that for you